# Prove $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{P(N(t)>0)}{t}=E(N(1))$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

A process $\{N(t)/ t\in [0, \infty]\}$ with $N (0)=0$ is called crudely stationary if $p_k(s, t) = P(N(t + s) - N (t) = k)$ depends only on the length $t-s$ and not on
$s$. It is called simple if, almost certainly, only if it has jump discontinuities of
size $1$. Prove that, for a simple crudely stationary process $N$, we have
what  $$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{P(N(t)>0)}{t}=E(N(1)).$$

I have been looking for information to solve this problem and I have found that I can apply the Korolyuk-Khinchin theorem, but I don't know how to apply it, also before using it I should demonstrate it and I cannot find any clear proof on the web. I also think that maybe the problem can be solved in another way, that's why I go to this place. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions and even more if they solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

(Do you acturally mean by *crudely stationary* that the distribution of $N(t+s)-N(t)$ depends only on $s$, not on $t$?)

If so, then here's an approach. Because $N$ has only unit jumps
$$
N(1) =\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n 1_{\{N(k/n)-N((k-1)/n)>0\}}.
$$
In effect, once $n$ is large enough, each interval $((k-1)/n,k/n]$ contains either precisely one jump or none. A little thought will reveal that the sum displayed above increases with $n$, so the monotone convergence theorem can be invoked. By crude stationarity, $E(1_{\{N(k/n)-N((k-1)/n)>0\}}) = E(1_{\{N(1/n)>0\}}) = P(N(1/n)>0)$.